# Low-level bluetooth utility

Tags: bluetooth

What's a bluetooth utility for Linux that will let me pair and unpair devices, display messages coming from a device, send messages to a device (hopefully done using the filesystem!), and set any available flags?

The application in mind is that I just want to have say 10 tiny bluetooth keyboards and map each key on each keyboard to send a MIDI message (obviously the midi part is not part of this OP).

Comment: Nice, thanks. But I would like to use obex push to send files instead of obex ftp. Is there a way?

Answer (score 24):

Here's a list of several tools dealing with Bluetooth that you can use to interact with a device.

#### hciconfig

`hciconfig`

- Gives info about the bluetooth hci on your pc
- Ensure the device is up and running and has required scan modes
- Running `hcitool dev` should also give some of this info

#### hcitool

`hcitool inq` and `hcitool scan`

- Gives info about or rather identifies nearby bluetooth devices

`hcitool info <BTAddr>`

- Get info about remote bluetooth device

#### l2ping

`l2ping <BTAddr>`

- One way to see if we can communicate with a remote bluetooth device

#### sdptool

`sdptool browse <BTAddr> or sdptool records <BTAddr>`

- Gives info about the services provided by a remote bluetooth device

#### obexftp

`obexftp –nopath –noconn –uuid none –bluetooth <BTAddr> –channel <OPUSHChann
elNo> –put <FileToPut>`

- Allows one to send file without specifying the pin on the remote device side
- The OPush channel number for device is got from sdptool above

`obexftp -b <BTAddr> -v -p <FileToPut>`

- Allows one to put a file onto the specified BT device
- obexftp could also be used to get or list the files on the BT device
- also allows one to identify a nearby BT device by just giving -b option

#### passkey-agent

`passkey-agent –default <Pin>`

- Pin specified here is what the remote BT device should provide
  or its user enter on that device when requested.

#### obexpushd

`obexpushd`

- Allows one to recieve files sent from a bluetooth device.
- Depending on who started it, the recieved files will be stored in the corresponding home directory

#### Pairing

You can following the directions from this site to pair a device with your Linux box via the command line. The aritcle is titled: [How to pair a bluetooth device from command line on Linux](http://www.heatxsink.com/entry/how-to-pair-a-bluetooth-device-from-command-line-on-linux).

#### Example

1. Find your bluetooth device mac address

   ```
   $ hcitool scan

   Scanning ...
       11:22:33:44:55:66   device 1
       12:34:56:78:90:12   device 2
   ```
2. Setup bluetooth-agent to pass the expected pairing code

   ```
   $ bluetooth-agent 0000 &
   ```
3. Edit the rfcomm config file `/etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf`, and put the MAC address from above, in it.

   ```
   rfcomm0 {
     # Automatically bind the device at startup
     bind no;
     # Bluetooth address of the device
     device 11:22:33:44:55:66;
     # RFCOMM channel for the connection
     channel 3;
     # Description of the connection
     comment "This is Device 1's serial port.";
   }
   ```

   **NOTE:** An important caveat, if you configure your device to not bind at startup (bind no;) you are going to have to manually spin up rfcomm using this command before using the serial port (which also requires root permissions).

   ```
   $ sudo rfcomm connect rfcomm0
   ```

#### References

- [Short and simple commandline Bluetooth in any new Linux distros](http://hanishkvc.wordpress.com/2007/05/16/short-and-simple-commandline-bluetooth-in-any-new-linux-distros/)