# How do I pair Microsoft Bluetooth Desktop keyboard and mouse

Tags: bluetooth

I recently bought the Microsoft Bluetooth Desktop keyboard and mouse ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B086QR6Q2S/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086QR6Q2S)) and i'm not able to get it to pair on Linux. It pairs only the mouse. I have read many of the other answers on here, to no avail. Does anybody have any ideas?

Its connecting to the keyboard, but its not pairing with it.

---

I am using Manjaro

Comment: Do any of the commands discussed in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93626/127903) help you pull together more helpful diagnostic data to include in your post? If not, where are you getting stuck using those commands to pair/use your bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: none of those commands are recognized on my system?